# Implement jQuery-like document.ready-Event

Tags: c#, events, asp.net-core

I'm creating a asp.net core application which is using the new HostedService-feature of asp.net core 2.1. Some of those services registered via `services.AddHostedService()` are dependant on other services and I'm looking for a way to notify the "child-services" when the "parent-service" gets ready.

My first implementation looked like this:

```
// Parent class
public delegate void OnServiceReadyHandler(object sender);
public event OnServiceReadyHandler OnServiceReady;

public void Init()
{
    // Do stuff
    OnServiceReady?.Invoke(this);
}


// Child class
_parentService.OnServiceReady += (sender) =>
{
   // Do stuff
};
```

But this leads to a problem when the child class subscribes to the OnServiceReady-Event after it already fired, therefore never getting notified.

I then thought about a property on the parent-class, something like `IsRead`, but this might as well lead to a race condition (between reading the property and subscribing to the ready-event).

Doing lots of web stuff lately [jQuerys `document.ready`-event](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) came to my mind. It fires after the document got ready or immediately if it is already in ready-state. I changed my implementation to this:

```
// Parent class
private bool IsReady { get; set; } = false;

public delegate void OnServiceReadyHandler(object sender);
private OnServiceReadyHandler onServiceReadyHandler;
public event OnServiceReadyHandler OnServiceReady
{
    add
    {
        if (!IsReady)
            onServiceReadyHandler = (OnServiceReadyHandler)Delegate.Combine(onServiceReadyHandler, value);
        else
            value(this); 
    }
    // Remove ...
}

public void Init()
{
    // Do stuff
    IsReady = true;
    OnServiceReady?.Invoke(this);
}


// Child class
_parentService.OnServiceReady += (sender) =>
{
   // Do stuff
};
```

This looks like it is working fine, but I'm wondering if there's a) still the chance of a race condition and the client not getting notified here and b) a more elegant solution to this problem or this implementation?

Comment: Why don’t you just register your services in the right order to make sure that they can depend on each other? Or alternatively, use an orchestrator service for this. But I wouldn’t really add event handling for this here. If you don’t want to make a service report that it’s ready when it has in fact still things to do, then don’t make it complete the start task yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can still have a race condition here:

```
if (!IsReady)
    onServiceReadyHandler = (OnServiceReadyHandler)Delegate.Combine(onServiceReadyHandler, value);
```

You could have a case where `IsReady` is evaluated to `false`, but before the event handler can be updated, the `Init()` method sets `IsReady` to `true` and fires the event. *Then* the second line above runs and the event never gets fired again.

The [example in the documentation for the `add` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/add) shows the use of [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement). That's probably what you should be using here - in the `add` and `remove` accessors, as well as in your `Init()` method.

Also, is there any reason you are using `Delegate.Combine()` here? The docs just show you can use `+=`.

```
public event OnServiceReadyHandler OnServiceReady
{
    add
    {
        lock (onServiceReadyHandler) {
            if (!IsReady)
                onServiceReadyHandler += value;
            else
                value(this); 
        }
    }
    // Remove ...
}

public void Init()
{
    // Do stuff
    lock (onServiceReadyHandler) {
        IsReady = true;
    }
    OnServiceReady?.Invoke(this);
}
```